# Will this Haskell code take too much memory?

Tags: haskell, tailrecursion-modulo-cons

As in this code:

```
import Data.Char
groupsOf _ [] = []
groupsOf n xs = 
    take n xs : groupsOf n ( tail xs )

problem_8 x = maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ x
main = do t <- readFile "p8.log" 
      let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
      print $ problem_8 digits
```

I realize that in Haskell many programs construct and seem to store some intermediate results, such as the `groupsOf` list in the above code. The above code is the reference answer for Euler project problem 8, taken from [Haskell website](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/1_to_10). The original question ask for the largest product of 5 consecutive digits in a very long chain of digits such as `45343231635723421312443535767983456`.
So the code will calculate all the products and store it as a list. In other languages I think they will only keep a temporary largest value and discard anything smaller.

So does `groupsOf` really stores all the intermediate results? what if the problem scales up? Will it allocate too much memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not because of `groupsOf`. That one will only need to keep one group in memory at a time. However, `maximum` might [build up a large thunk](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Space_leak#Building_up_unevaluated_expressions) since it's *too* lazy, so make sure to either compile with `-O` or `-O2` so that strictness analysis is performed, or use `foldl1' max` instead<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> `foldl1'` is found in `Data.List`</sub>

Answer (score 8):

> I realize that in Haskell many programs construct and seem to store some intermediate results, such as the groupsOf list in the above code.

"seem to" is a good thing to say here, because in all honesty this is where Haskell can really shine. It can, in fact, take up much *less* memory, without complicated micromanagement on your part, thanks to laziness.

One nifty thing about lazy IO (e.g. `readFile`) is that it will read only as much of the file as necessary, and the file can be garbage-collected as you consume its contents. (Well, roughly so. It depends on how you set the buffering.)

Here's a rough sketch of how your program will be executed:

```
t <- readFile "p8.log"
```

Create a thunk for the `t :: String`. Probably check that the file exists, and open it in read mode.

```
 let digits = map digitToInt $concat $ lines t
```

Create a thunk for `digits :: [Int]`

```
 print $ problem_8 digits
```

Once we attempt to execute this, all of the work will actually get done. We need to fully evaluate `problem_8 digits :: Int` in order to print it. So we create a thunk for `problem_8 digits` and force it.

```
maximum . map product . groupsOf 5 $ digits
```

At this point, `maximum` needs the first two elements of `map product . groupsOf 5 $ digits` in order to see which of the two is greater. Therefore `map product` needs to see the first two elements of `groupsOf 5 digits` to pass along.

Now, `groupsOf 5` will need the first 5 elements of `digits` in order to produce its first element. At this point, the first line of the file will probably be read, and go through the defined transformations. `groupsOf` can construct its first element, and probably its second element (assuming there are more than 6 characters on that line). `groupsOf 5 digits` passes its first two elements up the chain, we map `product` onto those two things, and then `maximum` checks which of the two is larger. We keep the result, the larger of the two.

At this point (in fact somewhat earlier than this point) we can *entirely discard* the intermediate results. The first two elements of `groupOf 5 digits` are now entirely unnecessary; we will never need to inspect them again, and the garbage collector can collect them anytime. The first two characters of that file will not be used anymore either, and can be discarded.

---

Now, this is extremely handwavey and possibly slightly inaccurate. But do you get the idea? Haskell is lazy (well technically Haskell is "non-strict", which is generally implemented via laziness), which makes its execution style *much* different than any strict language. This allows us to use what appears to be tons of intermediate representations and data structures, without *actually* taking up tons of memory. Good compilers, such as GHC, can optimize memory usage like you wouldn't believe.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "intermediate results" here, exactly...  But your code looks fine to me.  Specifically, your implementation of `groupsOf` is [tail recursive modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), so I don't think you'll have to worry about stack overflow, if that's what you're concerned about.

I might be misunderstanding your question, though.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Actually, tail recursion doesn't really mean anything in Haskell, since all functions, due to laziness, are essentially tail-call optimized for free.

Comment: @Dan Burton - that is not correct. Tail recursion is still very important for recursive functions where you don't want laziness.

Comment: @stephentetley - yes you're right. But most functions you write in Haskell *should* be lazy. (e,g, `groupsOf` is lazy.) For those few functions which you want/need to be strict, yes, tail recursion matters. A strict version of `maximum`, for example, would benefit from careful use of tail recursion, to avoid building up a large thunk, as hammar alluded to.